# Javascript Array items being overwritten

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a function that contains the following code:

```
stores = [];
console.log('in stores d.length is ', districts.length);
districts.forEach( function ( dis ) {
    dis.store.forEach( function( store ) {
        store.structure = dis.structure;
        store.structure.dis = dis.district_nbr;
        store.structure.sto = store.store_nbr;
        //store.message = getMessage(store.structure);
        console.log('store st is ', store.structure);
        stores.push( store );
    });
});
stores.forEach( function ( s ) {
    console.log("after set Master this is stores ", s.structure);
})
```

As the loops go, I initialize an object `structure` for each store starting out as the structure from the parent dis object which has a few fields and has been validated as correct. I then add an additional fields to the structure object to account for the district number and store number. Each dis object has a unique set of stores.

The `console.log` in the nested for loops displays the correct structure for the store. However, when I print them after the fact, the stores all have the final district number in the loop and the final store number in the loop instead of their respective correct values.

**QUESTION**: Does something happen in Array.push() that I'm not aware of that through things out of whack? I think my real question is what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clone the `dis.structure` to avoid modifying the same object in each iteration of the loop.

```
function clone(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

stores = [];
console.log('in stores d.length is ', districts.length);
districts.forEach( function ( dis ) {
    dis.store.forEach( function( store ) {
        store.structure = clone(dis.structure);
        store.structure.dis = dis.district_nbr;
        store.structure.sto = store.store_nbr;
        //store.message = getMessage(store.structure);
        console.log('store st is ', store.structure);
        stores.push( store );
    });
});
stores.forEach( function ( s ) {
    console.log("after set Master this is stores ", s.structure);
})
```

For more on deep-cloning objects, see [this answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/5344074#5344074).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you set `store.structure = dis.structure`, `store.structure` is now a *reference* to `dis.structure`, not a copy.

This means that every time you then mutate `store.structure`, you are in fact mutating the `dis.structure`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `dis.store`'s items are same as `stores` items, because your `stores`'s items are not values but references. So you put same references into 2 different arrays. And if you change the items from one reference, it will be updated also for the another one.

You need to copy them with `Object.assign`, but be aware it will copy only first level items
**Replace this line** `store.structure = dis.structure;` **with this**
`store.structure = Object.assign({}, dis.structure);`